# Object PHP guess number

Tags: php, class, object

I make "Guess my number in PHP " and I don't know how to make "tries", because right now I got 10 tries but it count down every time. I guess a number and after 10 tries, I can still guess the number.

I got 3 files. 
index.php
Guess.php
The last file is only a view with a form

Index.php file

```
<?php

// Guess my number

require __DIR__ . "/config.php";
require __DIR__ . "/autoload.php";

// Start a named session
session_name("maub");
session_start();

//Deal with incoming variables
$guess = $_POST["guess"] ?? null;
$doInit = $_POST["doInit"] ?? null;
$doGuess = $_POST["doGuess"] ?? null;
$doCheat = $_POST["doCheat"] ?? null;


// Settings for session.
$number = $_SESSION["number"] ?? null;
$tries = $_SESSION["tries"] ?? null;
$games = null;

// Init the game
if ($doInit || $number === null ) {
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    $games = new Guess();
    $_SESSION["number"] = $games->number();
    $_SESSION["tries"] = $games->tries();
} elseif ($doGuess) {
    $games = new Guess($number, $tries);
    $result = $games -> makeGuess($guess);
    $_SESSION["tries"] = $games -> tries();
}

// Render the page
require __DIR__ . "/view/guess_my_number.php";

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Guess.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Guess my number, a class supporting the game through GET, POST and SESSION.
 */
class Guess
{
    /**
    * @var int $number   The current secret number.
    * @var int $tries    Number of tries a guess has been made.
    */
    private $number = null;
    private $tries = 10;


    /**
    * Constructor to initiate the object with current game settings,
    * if available. Randomize the current number if no value is sent in.
    *
    * @param int $number The current secret number, default -1 to initiate
    *                    the number from start.
    * @param int $tries  Number of tries a guess has been made,
    *                    default 10.
    */

    public function __construct(int $number = -1, int $tries = 10)
    {
        $this->tries = $tries;
        if ($number === -1) {
            $number = rand(1,100);
        }
        $this->number = $number;
    }




    /**
    * Randomize the secret number between 1 and 100 to initiate a new game.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function random() : void
    {
        $this->number = rand(1, 100);
    }



    /**
    * Get number of tries left.
    *
    * @return int as number of tries made.
    */

    public function tries() : int
    {
        return $this->tries;
    }




    /**
    * Get the secret number.
    *
    * @return int as the secret number.
    */

    public function number() : int
    {
        return $this->number;
    }




    /**
    * Make a guess, decrease remaining guesses and return a string stating
    * if the guess was correct, too low or to high or if no guesses remains.
    *
    * @throws GuessException when guessed number is out of bounds.
    *
    * @return string to show the status of the guess made.
    */

    public function makeGuess(int $guess) : string
    {
        if ($guess < 1 || $guess > 100 ) {
            throw new GuessException("You can type only number between 1-100");
        }
        $this->tries--;

        if ($guess === $this->number) {
            $result = "Correct! Good Job";
            session_destroy();
        } elseif ($guess > $this->number) {
            $result = "Too high try again!";
        } else {
            $result = "Too low try again!";
        };
        return $result;
    }
}

<h1>Hey guess my number</h1>
<p>Guess a number between 1 and 100, you have <b><?= $tries ?></b> left.</p>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="guess">
    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?= $number ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="tries" value="<?= $tries ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="doGuess" value="Make guess">
    <input type="submit" name="doInit" value="Start from beginning">
    <input type="submit" name="doCheat" value="Cheat">
</form>


<?php if ($doGuess) : ?>
    <p>Your guess is : <?= $guess ?> is <?php echo $result ?>. </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($doCheat) :  ?>
    <p>Cheat: Current number is: <?= $number ?>. </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- <pre>
    <?= var_dump($_POST) ?>
</pre> -->
```

Comment: Where is the logic to stop after 10 tries?

Comment: @JasonK That is the problem I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you just need an if statement in your main logic.

```
if($games->tries() < 1 ){
  echo 'To many guesses';
  // Reset the game.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

on 22.6.2021 i wrote a **Guess Number in Range** [0 .. aMaxIntValue] sample Web Application using PHP. i think the following code may help you. the code is kept in a Single PHP file. it generates #4 HTML pages ...

- the 1st initial page is used to collect application parameters (e.g. the Max Int Number to Guess)
- the 2nd page is the Main Play Game Page where the user is asked to Guess the Secret Number or to Reset Game. this page shows the previous user guesses and some tips for the user about the guess
- the 3rd page is used to notify the user looses game (that is he has no more tries left)
- the 4th page is used to notify the user wins the game (that is the Guess was OK)

the Number of Tries left to the User is computed using the values range [0 .. max]

the Secret Number to Guess is a random generated integer number in the Range [0 .. max]

this is the PHP + HTML code ...

```
<?php

    session_start();

    error_reporting (E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR);

    function ResetGame()
    {
        unset ( $_SESSION['theMaxNumber'] );
    }

    function InitGame()
    {
        $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess'] = mt_rand (0, $_SESSION['theMaxNumber']);

        $_SESSION['theMaxNumberOfTries'] = floor ( log ($_SESSION['theMaxNumber'], 2) ) + 1;

        $_SESSION['theUserTriesCount'] = 0;

        $_SESSION['thePrevGuessesString'] = '';

        $_SESSION['theUserGuess'] = 0;
    }

    function ComputeNumberOfTriesLeft()
    {
        return $_SESSION['theMaxNumberOfTries'] - $_SESSION['theUserTriesCount'];
    }

    function IsNoMoreTriesLeft()
    {
        return ComputeNumberOfTriesLeft() <= 0;
    }

    $aCanPlayGame = false;

    $aUserSubmittedGuess = false;

    $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft = false;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        if ( isset ($_REQUEST['playgame']) ) {

            $_SESSION['theMaxNumber'] = intval($_REQUEST['theMaxNumber']);

            // init game ...
            InitGame();

            $aCanPlayGame = true;

        }
        elseif ( isset ($_REQUEST['submituserguess']) ) {

            $aCanPlayGame = true;

            $aUserSubmittedGuess = true;

            $_SESSION['theUserGuess'] = intval($_REQUEST['theUserGuess']);

        }
        elseif ( isset ($_REQUEST['resetgame']) ) {

            ResetGame();

        }
        else {
            ResetGame();
        }

    }
    else {
        ResetGame();
    }

    // check a play

    $aUserShouldTryLower = false;
    $aUserShouldTryHigher = false;

    $aUserWins = false;

    $aUserLooses = false;

    if ($aCanPlayGame) {

        $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft = IsNoMoreTriesLeft();

        if ( ! $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft ) {

            // user have tries left

            if ($aUserSubmittedGuess) {

                // check user guess ...
                $aUserGuess = intval($_SESSION['theUserGuess']);

                if ( $aUserGuess > $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess'] ) {

                    $aUserShouldTryLower = true;

                }
                elseif ( $aUserGuess < $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess'] ) {

                    $aUserShouldTryHigher = true;

                }
                else {

                    $aUserWins = true;

                    // also reset game
                    ResetGame();

                }

                // add the current guess to the prev guesses string
                $_SESSION['thePrevGuessesString'] .= $_SESSION['theUserGuess'] . ' ';

                // increase the user tries count
                ++ $_SESSION['theUserTriesCount'];

                // check tries count
                if ( ! $aUserWins ) {

                    $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft = IsNoMoreTriesLeft();

                    if ($aIsNoMoreTriesLeft) {
                        // this was the last try

                        // no more tries left
                        $aUserLooses = true;

                        // also reset game
                        ResetGame();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        else {
            // no more tries left
            $aUserLooses = true;

            // also reset game
            ResetGame();
        }

    }

?>

<?php if ($aUserLooses): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Sorry, you loose the game</p>
    <p>the Number to Guess was <?php echo $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess']; ?></p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="resetgame" value="reset game">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php elseif ($aUserWins): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Congrats, you Win the Game</p>
    <p>the Number to Guess was <?php echo $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess']; ?></p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="resetgame" value="reset game">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php elseif ($aCanPlayGame): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>the Max Number is <?php echo $_SESSION['theMaxNumber']; ?></p>
    <p>Guess a Number in the Range [ 0 .. <?php echo ($_SESSION['theMaxNumber']); ?> ]</p>
    <p>[DEBUG] the secret number to guess is <?php echo $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess']; ?></p>
    <p>you have <?php echo ComputeNumberOfTriesLeft(); ?> tries left</p>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="theUserGuess">Enter your Guess: </label>
        <input type="text" id="theUserGuess" name="theUserGuess">
        <input type="submit" name="submituserguess" value="Guess">
        <input type="submit" name="resetgame" value="reset game">
    </form>
    <p>Prev Guesses: <?php echo $_SESSION['thePrevGuessesString']; ?> </p>
    <p>
        <?php
            if ($aUserShouldTryLower) {
                echo 'you should try a lower < guess';
            }
            elseif ($aUserShouldTryHigher) {
                echo 'you should try a higher > guess';
            }
            else {
                echo 'no guess';
            }
        ?>
    </p>

</body>
</html>

<?php else: ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Guess a Number from (0) to ... </p>
    <form method="post">
        <input id="theMaxNumber" name="theMaxNumber">
        <input type="submit" name="playgame" value="play game">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php endif; ?>
```

that's all folks ...